# How to edit a readonly zip file?

Tags: binary-file

I tried to edit a zip file and change its content using the following commands

```
:set modifiable
:%s/xxA/..\//g
:x!
```

But it returned the following error

```
W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file
55 substitutions on 10 lines
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

After I pressed Enter nothing changed. Please guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you intend to accomplish?

Comment: I want to test this experiment [ https://blog.silentsignal.eu/2014/01/31/file-upload-unzip]

Answer (score 3):

Vim ships with the *zip plugin* (`:help pi_zip`) that lets you automatically browse and edit the *contents* of the zip file. These browse buffers are read-only. In order to read the actual zip file, you need to use *binary mode*: `$ vim -b archive.zip`.

If you did use binary mode, the readonly buffer originates from the zip file's file system permissions. Sometimes you can force a write with `:w!`, else you have to first give your user write access (`$ chmod +w archive.zip`).